Проблема одновременной работы пользователей на win и linux в 1c77
Есть компьютер с linux с установленной WINE@Etersoft. Когда пользователь с windows подключается к разшаренной папке с базой 1с77, пользователь с linux не может работать с этой базой. 1с77 пишет что программа завершена аварийно и просит восстановить индексы.
Подскажите пожалуйста чем это может быть вызвано и как решить эту проблему.

База 1с77 должна лежать в папке, которая расшаренна с Виндовс. С папками, расширенными на Линукс 1с работать может только монопольно.
Это связанно с тем что драйвер cifs или самба(не помню уже) неправильно блокируют файл. Можно попробовать драйвер cifs от Ethersoft - там вроде исправленно
Лучшее решение - терминальный сервер и работа без шар.
